# ReactJs and sling CMS connectivity

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aem, sling

I'm new to sling, so now I wanted to connect sling CMS with ReactJS Application to dynamically change the data in the front end page with out disturbing the structure of the front end application. To connect ReactJS with Sling CMS, AEM is needed? or any other ways to connect ReactJS with sling CMS

Answer (score 1):

First sling is not CMS. [Sling](https://sling.apache.org/) is a java based framework for building RESTful services and applications. AEM is built using JCR Jackrabbit, Apache Sling and few more other technologies.

If you are looking for adding a CMS application to your React app, there are multiple opensource headless CMS tools available like Sanity, Contentful etc.

AEM is little ahead in this game, with its [SPA editor](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/developing/headless/spas/spa-overview.html?lang=en), combing its powerful CMS capabilities added on top of React/Angular based SPA applications.
But to mention, inorder to use AEM SPA editor features, you ll also need to refactor the react app.

Choice depends on business usecase, training, license etc.